# How to debug when get error from D3

Tags: debugging, d3.js

All:

I wonder if anyone could give me some clue that how to track the bug in D3.

For example, I draw a linechart, and I got some error from D3:

```
 Error: Invalid value for <line> attribute y2="NaN" d3.js:7571
```

And this error is most possibly caused by some illegal(no value or NaN or etc) data binding in my code, but how can I trace back to locate where this error happen in my code rather in D3?

Thanks

Comment: You're going to have to look at the code that you're using to generate the y2 value.  If this is a `d3.svg.line` generator, then you should probably start looking there.  I would suggest that if this is the case, your `y` accessor function is probably returning some crappy values at some point.

Comment: @BenLyall Thanks, I finally find the error by read line by line. This is a nightmare!

Answer (score 0):

I find that using the console in the Google Chrome browser is useful.

This can be enabled by pressing F12 when on the offending page and a separate window will open at the bottom.

The console tab on this window will present with information on errors found in the page.

As an example I inserted a 'random' semicolon in my d3.js code here;

[image]

(this is in the 'Geany' editor)

And in the console tab the error is identified as follows;

[image]

This shows you a description of the error and an indication of the area. In this case the console errored on the following line because it regards the semi-colon as valid, but that makes the following code invalid, but you get the idea.

In Firefox there is a plug-in called firebug I believe that will allow the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, there's isn't a really good way to debug this kind of error, but there's a workaround.

The error is thrown when an attribute value is set to `NaN`. Actually, that by itself would be easy to debug, because you could expand the error in the console and look through the stack trace to find in which file and on which line within call the stack the `NaN` value is set.

But that becomes impossible when you also have a transition. That's because the `attr()` call that's ultimately responsible for setting a `NaN` value runs asynchronously (i.e. via `setTimeout` at a later time). So you no longer get a stack trace that lets you see where in your code the `NaN` came from.

So, as a workaround, you can temporarily comment out all the transitions in your code, reload the page and you'll get an error that'll point you towards the line with the bug.

If you don't want to do that, then the only other option you have is to look at your code. You can narrow things down to the places in the code where you set attributes on a `<line>` node (since the error is about a `<line>`). Then you can insert a `debugger` statement in that general area and step through your code to find what causes your it to output `NaN`.